# Typescript + React: Recieve Date object as a date type and pass it on to another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date, types, properties

I've taken a user assigned date from props of a parent component and am merely trying to pass that date on to another component.

```
import Card from '../UI/Card';
import ExpenseDate from './ExpenseDate';
import './ExpenseItem.module.css'

type Form = {
   title: string;
   amount: number;
   date: Date;
}

const ExpenseItem = ({ title, amount, date }: Form) => {

   //Return Date UI Component
   return (
   <li>
      <Card className="expense-item">
         <ExpenseDate date={date} />
         <div className="expense-item__description">
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <div className="expense-item__price">${amount}</div>
         </div>
      </Card>
   </li>
   );
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```

to

```
import './ExpenseDate.module.css';
const ExpenseDate = (date: Date) => {
   //Retrieve Day Month and Year from Date object
   const month = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'long'});
   const day = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {day: '2-digit'});
   const year = date.getFullYear();

   //Return Dates to Date UI Component
   return (
      <div className="expense-date">
         <div className="expense-date__month">{month}</div>
         <div className="expense-date__day">{day}</div>
         <div className="expense-date__year">{year}</div>
      </div>
   )
};
export default ExpenseDate;
```

but I get the error

```
<ExpenseDate date={date} />
Type '{ date: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Date'.
```

Property 'date' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Date'.
I didn't think I was trying to pass off "date" as a property of a Date object but that's what I'm understanding it's trying to say and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpenseDate is not typed with typescript. Moreover you are accessing the props in a wrong way.
Try to use it like this.

```
export type ExpenseDateProps = {
  date: Date;
}
const ExpenseDate: FC<ExpenseDateProps> = ({ date }) => {
   //Retrieve Day Month and Year from Date object
   const month = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'long'});
   const day = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {day: '2-digit'});
   const year = date.getFullYear();

   //Return Dates to Date UI Component
   return (
      <div className="expense-date">
         <div className="expense-date__month">{month}</div>
         <div className="expense-date__day">{day}</div>
         <div className="expense-date__year">{year}</div>
      </div>
   )
};
export default ExpenseDate;
```